# Append variable and increment variable for each NR

Tags: awk

I want to turn a list of websites into some hideous java code so that I can run it in selenium.

```
  http://google.com
  http://facebook.com
```

into

```
  public void goToWebsite1() {driver = new FirefoxDriver();driver.get("http://google.com");driver.quit();
  public void goToWebsite2() {driver = new FirefoxDriver();driver.get("http://facebook.com");driver.quit();
```

Seeing as I'm completely incompetent, I've contrived to do it like this:

```
  sed 's/$/");driver.quit();/g' homepage2
```

plus

```
  sed 's/^/() {driver = new FirefoxDriver();driver.get("/g'
```

plus

```
  prepend and increment counter
```

plus

```
  sed 's/^/public void goToWebsite/g'
```

unfortunately I don't know how to prepend and increment a counter on each line. I'll bet there's an awk one liner. I imagine something like:

```
    awk {x=1} {NR = gsub/^/x} {x=x+1}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best not to modify NR. Here's the quick way:

```
awk '{ print "public void goToWebsite" NR "() {driver = new FirefoxDriver();driver.get(\"" $0 "\");driver.quit();" }' file
```

Results:

```
public void goToWebsite1() {driver = new FirefoxDriver();driver.get("http://google.com");driver.quit();
public void goToWebsite2() {driver = new FirefoxDriver();driver.get("http://facebook.com");driver.quit();
```

Comment: Well... that's elegant. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With sed:

```
sed = input | 
  sed 'N;s!\(.*\)\n\(.*\)!public void goToWebsite\1() {driver = new FirefoxDriver();driver.get("\2");driver.quit();!'
```